# Stop web view bounce shows error

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift

Trying to stop the webview from bouncing, when user drags the app/screen down there is a blank space appears on top. This is the code which is not working:

```
#import "Webview.h"

@interface Webview ()

@end

@implementation Webview
@synthesize webView;
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    NSString *urlAddress= [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"demos/index" ofType:@"html"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: urlAddress];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    [webView loadRequest:requestObj];

    webView.scrollView.delegate = self;

    webView.scrollView.bounces = NO;
  }




- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
    //The webview is is scrolling
    int yPosition = [[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: @"scrollY"] intValue];

    if([[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: @"document.body.offsetHeight"] intValue] - yPosition == webView.frame.size.height)
    {
        //The user scrolled to the bottom of the webview
        webView.scrollView.bounces = YES;
    }else if([[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: @"document.body.offsetHeight"] intValue] - yPosition > webView.frame.size.height + 100){
        webView.scrollView.bounces = NO;
    }

}

- (void)scrollViewDidScrollToTop:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
    NSLog(@"Finish");
}



/*
#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

@end
```

Having message: Assigning to 'id _Nullable' from omcompatible type 'Webview *const __strong'

Answer (score 0):

If that error is on the line:

```
_webView.scrollView.delegate = self;
```

...then the error is that your `webView` instance is not the correct type.

1. Check that your `webView` instance is a subclass of `UIWebView`.
2. You should be adopting the `UIScrollViewDelegate` protocol, by including a protocol declaration for the interface: `@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate>`

Comment: Should I put `@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate>` instead of `@interface Webview ()` ?

Comment: As long as you adopt the `UIScrollViewDelegate`, you should be fine. If you are still getting that error, then set a breakpoint where you can access the class, and print out the classes class in the console, using `po [var_name class]`